# Is it possible to download TeX Live in a separate, single file?

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

Installation through the internet is so harsh...

For example, is there a torrent for TeX Live?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to have a "resume/pause"- like feature when downloading TeXLive then mirroring it on your hard drive is a good approach.

### Advantages of mirroring TeXLive:

1. We can pause or resume the download.
2. We can share the raw TeX distribution for other users in our local network. As a result, we save internet bandwidth.
3. We can update or sync our single raw TeX mirror with a public nearest mirror on the internet. The installed TeX systems on the local network then update from our local mirror. It saves internet bandwidth. Updating or syncing  our local mirror with a public mirror runs fast because a smart algorithm has been adopted in a sync tool that will be used and explained below.

### How to mirror:

I assume that your OS is Windows. Otherwise, you need to search for similar procedures.

1. First download  `cwrsync` version 5.5 from [itefix.net](https://itefix.net/cwrsync) (the download link is in the "free" tab). Unpack it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and add `C:\Program Files (x86)\cwrsync_5.5.0_x86_free\bin` to your system variable `PATH`.
2. Fix the file permission issue by doing the procedures explained in [this link](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/02/07/windows-rsync-jboss-developer-studio/).
3. Locate the nearest TeXLive mirror, and execute the following from `cmd`.

   ```
   rsync -a --delete -v --progress rsync://<your nearest mirror>/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ "/cygdrive/<your drive name>/<your destination folder>"
   ```

For example,

```
rsync -a --delete -v --progress rsync://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/ "/cygdrive/d/Installers/TeXLive2020"
```

For more detailed, please visit [Downloading/mirroring the TeX Live repository](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html)

### Tips and Trick:

Typing

```
rsync -a --delete -v --progress rsync://<your nearest mirror>/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ "/cygdrive/<your drive name>/<your destination folder>"
```

seems to be cumbersome for us. Therefore, I suggest you to create a batch file as follows

```
rem this filename is UpdateMyTeXLive.bat

rem the file path must not contain spaces
rem trailing / at the destionation is optional


rsync -a --delete -v --progress rsync://<your nearest mirror>/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ "/cygdrive/<your drive name>/<your destination folder>"
```

and name it something like

[image]

Whenever  you want to update your local TeX mirror, just right click the icon and choose "Run as administrator".

### Updating the installed TeX system:

Updating  your local TeXLive mirror has nothing to do with updating your installed TeXLive.

If you have installed TeXLive on your machine and you have just updated your local TeX mirror, then the installed TeXLive on your machine must be updated or synced with your local TeX mirror. To update your installed TeXLive see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55493/9467).

Comment: Higgs thanks for support. Cwrsync has to be bought, right? Or there are other alternative ways...

Comment: cwrsync download

Comment: Interesting approach. Cwrsync does appear to be a paid product, but you could always install Cygwin plus rsync (from the cygwin package manager) for a free solution.

Comment: The `SET CYGWIN=nontsec` was the key to get around those permission hassles I had. For what it's worth, I used [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which comes with a bundled `rsync.exe` for free which works without a complete cygwin environment which can be intimidating.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest to download one ISO file from a mirror of your choice or *via* Torrent. You can find some links [here](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html).

I think, now more than ever, that this is the most advantagious way to acquire TeXLive because the 2012 version has been released few days ago, so the DVD is really up-to-date at the moment and, with torrent or with a good mirror, you'll have it in two or three hours (with a good internet connection). 2.2 GiB is not a big deal nowadays

Comment: thanks. That was really helpful. I was wondering if the file I'm downloading was the right one. (It was 2.15 GiB similarly.)


Spike, is it the right one?
http://mirror-cybernet.lums.edu.pk/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2012-20120701.iso

Comment: Looking at the date and at the weight, yes it should