# Download MiKTeX + all packages

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

I would like to know where I could find an installer for MiKTeX embedding all existing LaTeX packages (if it exists). I am going to install LaTeX on a computer which will not ever be connected to Internet, and which won't allow amovible media (USB key/CD-ROM/...) as soon as everything is set up. So basically, I have to do a "one-shot" installation. I still do not know my needs in term of LaTeX packages, so I am wondering if a version of MiKTeX embedding all existing LaTeX packages existed.

I would like to install it on a Windows computer.

Comment: It seems your best shot would be to purchase the [MiKTeX DVD image](http://miktex.org/dvd) for 10 €. All the other installers/downloads need an Internet connection on the target computer at least once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the installer of the complete MikTeX downloader by choosing either

- [MikTeX 32 bit](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x86/setup-2.9.6942.exe) or
- [MikTeX 64 bit](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64/setup-2.9.6942-x64.exe)

Once you have finished downloading, you have to run it to bring up the dialog window as follows.

[image]

Select download MikTeX and you will be prompted to choose a mirror. After completing the download, you can burn all in a DVD and it is ready to be installed on any Windows machines.

Another option to MikTeX is TeXLive, you can make a mirror in your computer and distribute the mirror to any computers by sharing the LAN or burning it into a DVD. For more detailed explanation on mirroring TeXLive, see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63263/19356).

Comment: link is dead...

Comment: An updated link would be really helpful

Comment: If you edit the link to point to a newer MikTeX version, please always use `http://mirrors.ctan.org/` and not a specific mirror. You can always find the download at https://miktex.org/download (All downloads > Net Installer) as well (in case the link here points to an outdated version again). Please note also that the answer specifically links to the `setup-***.exe`, which has the option to download all of MikTeX and *not* to `basic-miktex-***.exe`, which only has an install option.

Comment: To make it absolutely clear: This answer was specifically written for the situation in the question, where the user wants to download *all of MikTeX* at once. If you are just looking to install MikTeX normally (and are OK with downloading additional files during that process and afterwards) you are probable fine with the `basic-miktex` installer and don't need `setup`. Just go to https://miktex.org/download and download the recommended installer for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can visit the [MikTeX homepage](http://miktex.org/), and down portable or DVD from browsering tab. after  downloading the portable,you can unzip it to folder such as MikTeX, then launch "miktex-portable.cmd" which would always be in the folder MikTeX, right click on the icon in the windows tray, selecting "MikTeX package manager", the so-called MPM. selecting "edit" then "select installable package" and right click the selections, you will see a plus symbol which means installing selecting packages.

the MiKTeX DVD-R should include all the packages as it says "if you install the basic MiKTeX system, then missing packages can be installed on-the-fly from the DVD-R".

Comment: Seems to be obsolete; http://miktex.org/dvd says it's not available.