# Example code of PSTricks in MikTeX

Tags: pstricks, miktex, plot, technical-drawing

everyone, in the past one hour, I have been fighting with the PSTricks package in MikTeX. I found a lot of example code [here](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Physics/physics#glidingBall).

For example, I downloaded the gliding ball example tex and I ran it in Miktex, but it didn't compile even though I installed all kinds of pst packages. And I tried some other example tex code, and they didn't work in Miktex neither.

Can someone help me modify one of the example code in the link above to make it work in MikTeX?

I'll really appreciate that! Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you compile with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence?

Comment: What do you mean? I am not that familiar with the compiling order. Could you please explain a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: or run the example with `xelatex`

Comment: @Herbert, I indeed tried that, but it still gave me error message. For example, in the gilding ball example, it says “! I can't find file `xdvipdfmx.cfg'.”

Comment: Look into the package manager of MikTeX for xetex or that file and controll if it is really installed.

Comment: @Herbert, yea, I just re-checked that, and I think I've installed "xetex-pstricks" as well.

Comment: then update the file name data base FNDB from the update window.

Comment: ? what do you mean by this?

Comment: FWIW, pstricks works fine in texlive OOTB. I never used Miktex because texlive is multiplatform and Miktex is not.

Comment: MikTeX->MAintenance->General->Refresh FNDB

Answer (score 3):

To diagnose your problem whether or not you have properly installed MikTeX, compile the following by invoking the following command from the DOS window (type `Win+R`, type `cmd` and press enter to launch the DOS window).

```
latex input.tex
dvips input.dvi
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None input.ps
```

```
% input.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\makeatletter
\degrees[4] 
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \foreach \a in {65,66,...,68}{\rput{\a}(!1 \a\space \pst@angleunit PtoC){\char\a}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you get the same result then everything is fine.

Comment: It gave me the following error "! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found." after I typed input.tex

Comment: @Cancan: Very good, now the easiest procedure to fix your problem is to download MikTeX and reinstall it. It is a brute force approach but it will save your time. See [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136198/19356) if you don't know how to get MikTeX.

Comment: Haha@ :D , I like this comment. Ok, I'll try that and see what happens again. Thanks!