# [Solved]: Tex Live 2020 installation failed on Windows 10

Tags: texlive, installing, texlive-2020

I downloaded Tex Live 2020 ISO file from CTAN mirror. I mounted the ISO file on disk D. Then I double click `install-tl-windows.bat` to install it. It went pretty good until the end of the installation:

```
Installing [3516/3518, time/total: 01:58:09/01:58:12]: zwgetfdate [242k]
Installing [3517/3518, time/total: 01:58:11/01:58:13]: zwpagelayout [630k]
Installing [3518/3518, time/total: 01:58:14/01:58:15]: zxjafont [181k]
Retrying to install: gregoriotex.win32 [274k]
TLUtils::untar: D:\tlpkg\installer\tar.exe xmf C:\Users\shuaiy\AppData\Local\Temp\gFu3Ujnkip\VKOEdiPsuX/gregoriotex.win32.r53994.tar failed (in C:/texlive/2020)
TLPDB::_install_package: untar failed
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
```

I tried 2 times, all give me the same error. From above error message, it seems installer was trying to untar something by calling `tar.exe` from mounted disk D. I navigate to `D:\tlpkg\installer\` in Cmd, and calling `tar.exe xmf` to test. And it gives:

```
D:\tlpkg\installer>tar.exe xmf
tar: option requires an argument -- f
Try `tar --help' for more information.
```

BTW, I do find another version of `tar.exe` on my computer located at `C:\Windows\System32` folder. This version of `tar.exe` seems OK with the argument `-f`.

Now I'm confused which step went wrong. Somebody please help me out.

[Solution]: issue fixed by using latest install-tl-windows.exe found in https:///CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ directory, rather than using huge texlive2020-20200406.iso file.

Thank everyone for helping me!

Comment: I downloaded texlive2020-20200406.iso, which is the latest version I can find.

Comment: Read this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63263/87876

Comment: You are missing the file name in your tar command (gregorio....tar). Did you try if the rest of the installation work? Can you eg compile with pdflatex a small file?